# Creating tree structures with lambda expression and defaultdict

Tags: python, recursion

The below code example uses a recursive definition. To my understanding, whenever a key is defined, its corresponding value is set as a dictionary as default. This way of definition allows arbitrary depth.

```
import collections
tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
some_dict = tree()
some_dict['color']['favor'] = "yellow"
```

However, I do not understand why not defining as the following way:

```
import collections
tree = collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict)
```

It seems both way work correctly. They both allow defining dictionary of arbitrary depth. Are they different in any sense?

Comment: The second example will not create a nested defaultdict with arbitrary depth, it will only work for 1 level "deep"

Comment: Surely the second way will cause an error at sufficient depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are far from equivalent in that the second one does not create arbitrary nesting depth:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

some_dict_1 = tree()
some_dict_2 = defaultdict(defaultdict)
```

Now, check out some deeper access:

```
>>> some_dict_1[1][2][3][4] = 5  # works fine
>>> some_dict_2[1][2][3][4] = 5
KeyError: 2
```

Also note that a plain `defaultdict` as default factory isn't worth much more than a simple `dict` as it will create missing values as `defaultdict()`, i.e. without a default factory of its own:

```
>>> some_dict_2[1][2]
KeyError: 2
```

even though `some_dict_2[1]` is a `defaultdict` ("by name, not by game"):

```
>>> some_dict_2[1]
defaultdict(None, {})
```